# Clone code from TFS to Github

Tags: visual-studio, github, tfs, repository

Hello I have project which I manage with visual Studio Online and tfs basic online.
But I need to share the code with coworkers who don't want to create MS accounts so they don't have access to the vs online code repository.

Can you tell me if there is any easy way to clone code from one repository to the other?

I'll be gratefull if anyone suggest me tools I should download to clone my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GitExtensions, for example, to do this.

1. Clone Repository from TFS Server (the url is in the Code-Explorer of the TFS Website)
2. Set the Origin Remote (Remotes/Manage Remote Repositories, there you can set the path of the github Remote (is written somewhere on the website))
3. Push (for example via GitExstensions)

Comment: Sad to say but I have no idea how to do this :x